# Trying to select environment in GitLab CI with multi/optional manual steps

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So you all can guide me in a different direction if I'm way off track.

I want to add a manual step that has the user choose which environment they want to build to. This step will set variables for the following steps to build with.
My issue is that the Build step won't trigger unless all of the previous manual steps are run because I need to set `allow_failure: false`. If I do not set that, then the CI will skip the manual Env step.

I want to make it so the Build step triggers if only 1 of the Env steps are successful.

[image: Image of my desired process]

Here is my desired process.

Comment: I thought I had this, but I deleted my answer because it wasn't working.